# Outlook Oauth .default suffix error trying smtp and imap after getting token

Tags: oauth-2.0, ouath-outlook

Im trying to access an Outlook email using Oauth , Already set this permissions on Azure App:

[image]

So, using Oauth 2.0 client credentials grant I obtain the access Token:

[image]

But, when I try to authenticate with that token it fails, so I read that it was necessary to generate a second token call using that first one as a parameter and using imap and smtp scopes concatenated, and I tried like in the examples:

[image]

And as you see, I get this suffix error :

```
    {
        "error": "invalid_scope",
        "error_description": "AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send 
is not valid. Client credential flows must have a 
scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).\r\nTrace ID: 41d2086b-f83e-41d8-b405-115249b27901\r\nCorrelation ID: 6afef855-3fc9-4259-864b-4ec8e293e9d0\r\nTimestamp: 2022-04-29 00:02:06Z",
        "error_codes": [
            1002012
        ],
        "timestamp": "2022-04-29 00:02:06Z",
        "trace_id": "41d2086b-f83e-41d8-b405-115249b27901",
        "correlation_id": "6afef855-3fc9-4259-864b-4ec8e293e9d0"
    }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?, why the first token its not enough or how do I get the access one in the second call ?

Thanks in advance !!